# 502 Bad Gateway when accessing virtual host via Jwilder's Nginx proxy

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose

I've got a Nginx-proxy (Jwilder, default config) and Gitlab-Instance running on the same host.
`git.myhost.com` points to the host IP.
When starting Gitlab with the `docker-compose.yml` below I get a `502 Bad Gateway` upon accessing http://git.myhost.com.

The generated `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` in the nginx-proxy container looks fine as well:

```
upstream git.myhost.com {
                # 2ab9168d-c69e-4725-8c20-31a194ad8d07
                server 172.17.0.13 vhost;
}
server {
        server_name git.myhost.com;
        listen 80 ;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://git.myhost.com;
        }
}
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Here's Gitlab's `docker-compose.yml`:

```
gitlab-server:
  hostname: git.myhost.com
  expose:
  - "8100"
  ports:
  - 8101:22/tcp
#  - 8100:8100/tcp
  labels:
    io.rancher.sidekicks: gitlab-data
  environment:
    GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
      external_url 'http://git.myhost.com'
      gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 8101
    VIRTUAL_HOST: git.myhost.com
    VIRTUAL_PORT: 8100
  image: gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
  volumes_from:
  - gitlab-data

gitlab-data:
  labels:
    io.rancher.container.start_once: 'true'
  entrypoint:
  - /bin/true
  hostname: gitdata
  image: gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
  volumes:
  - /etc/gitlab:/etc/gitlab
  - /var/log/gitlab:/var/log/gitlab
  - /var/opt/gitlab:/var/opt/gitlab
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change nginx as below:

```
upstream gitlab {
                # 2ab9168d-c69e-4725-8c20-31a194ad8d07
                server 172.17.0.13:8100;
}
server {
        server_name git.myhost.com;
        listen 80 ;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://gitlab;
        }
}
```

172.17.0.13 is an ip address of gitlab docker container.

Answer (score 1):

One of the common issues that may cause this problem, is running the container outside of the `nginx-proxy` network, which is eventually unreachable by the `nginx-proxy`.

In order to run it in the same network as `nginx-proxy`, first, you need to find out in what network `nginx-proxy` is running. Just run the following command to find out:

```
docker network ls -f driver=bridge --format "{{.ID}}" | xargs docker network inspect | grep Name
```

It should give you the something like this:

```
    "Name": "bridge",
            "Name": "influxdb",
            "Name": "mariadb",
    "Name": "http_proxy",
            "Name": "web-app",
            "Name": "proxy",
            "Name": "grafana",
```

Now I can see that the container with the name `proxy` is under the network named `http_proxy`.
all I have to do, is to run the new container within this network by adding the flag `--network http_proxy` (replace the `http_proxy` with your network name):

```
docker run -d --name test --network http_proxy -h test.local -e VIRTUAL_HOST=test.local -v "$PWD":/usr/share/nginx/html nginx
```

Hope this helps.
Good luck!